# SQL Server query with group by a field error

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016, sql-query-store

I have the following table `MyTable`:

```
 id │ value_two │ value_three │ value_four 
────┼───────────┼─────────────┼────────────
  1 │ a         │ A           │ AA
  2 │ a         │ A2          │ AA2
  3 │ b         │ A3          │ AA3
  4 │ a         │ A4          │ AA4
  5 │ b         │ A5          │ AA5
```

I want to query an array of objects `{ value_three, value_four }` grouped by `value_two`. `value_two` should be present on its own in the result. The result should look like this:

```
 value_two │                                                                                    value_four                                                                                 
───────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 a         │ [{"value_three":"A","value_four":"AA"}, {"value_three":"A2","value_four":"AA2"}, {"value_three":"A4","value_four":"AA4"}]
 b         │ [{"value_three":"A3","value_four":"AA3"}, {"value_three":"A5","value_four":"AA5"}]
```

In postgress I can do this:

```
SELECT value_two
     , json_agg(row_to_json((value_three, value_four)::foo)) AS value_four
FROM   mytable
GROUP  BY value_two
```

But in SQL SERVER I  get `'json_array_elements' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

What is the equivalent to this on SQL SERVER. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: You need to generate a JSON output. Starting from SQL Server 2016, you may use `FOR JSON`. What is your current version?

Comment: I want to group results like in the second table, is it possible to do it in SQL server?

Comment: @Zhorov I have SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2016+, you may try to use `FOR JSON`:

Table:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   (1, 'a', 'A',  'AA'),
   (2, 'a', 'A2', 'AA2'),
   (3, 'b', 'A3', 'AA3'),
   (4, 'a', 'A4', 'AA4'),
   (5, 'b', 'A5', 'AA5')
) v (id, value_two, value_three, value_four)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT d.value_two, j.value_four
FROM Data d
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT value_three, value_four
   FROM Data
   WHERE value_two = d.value_two
   FOR JSON AUTO
) j (value_four)
```

Result:

```
value_two value_four
a         [{"value_three":"A","value_four":"AA"},{"value_three":"A2","value_four":"AA2"},{"value_three":"A4","value_four":"AA4"}]
b         [{"value_three":"A3","value_four":"AA3"},{"value_three":"A5","value_four":"AA5"}]
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I asked.  I have one other question: If "Data" is not a table but another complex query  `SELECT * FROM ... `. What you recommend cause I will have to do the same query one at main  `FROM Data ` and the other on the inside `OUTER APPLY` ?

Comment: @onwkbapzjamrhoescc, a statement like `; WITH (SELECT * FROM ...) AS Data SELECT DISTINCT d.value_two, j.value_four FROM Data d OUTER APPLY (SELECT value_three, value_four FROM Data WHERE value_two = d.value_two FOR JSON AUTO) j (value_four)` is an option. Note, that the statement before `WITH` must be followed by a semicolon.

Comment: @Zhorov "the statement before WITH must be **terminated** with a semicolon". And why not just mention that all statements should be terminated - including your suggestion.